# Prove Kähler Differential is always surjective using universal property.

Tags: commutative-algebra, universal-property

Let $A$ be an $R$-Algebra. An $R$-linear [derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) $d \colon A \to \Omega_{A/R}$ is called *universal derivation* or *Kähler differential* if for every $R$-linear derivation $D \colon A \to M$ there is a unique $A$-linear map $\Omega_{A/R} \to M$ making
$$ A \xrightarrow{d} \Omega_{A/R} $$
$$ \searrow  \hspace{.6cm} \downarrow$$
$$ \hspace{1cm} M $$
commute.  I want to show that $d$ is always surjective and this is what I've tried:

- It can easily be checked that $d \colon A \to \text{im}(d)$ is also a universal derivation. So $\Omega_{A/R}$ must be isomorphic to $\text{im}(d)$ with a unique isomorphism between them.
- (We are not yet done since we want *equality* between $\text{im}(d)$ and $\Omega_{A/R}$. I tried plugging in $M = \text{im}(d)$ in the diagram above and use the uniqueness, but it didn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the construction of Kahler differential, we know that $\Omega_{A/R}$ can be seen as $F/E$, where $F$ is generated by symbols $da$,here $a\in A$, $E$ is generated by symbols $dr$($r\in R$) and $d(a_1+a_2)-da_1-da_2$ as well as $d(a_1a_2)-da_1 \cdot a_2-a_1\cdot da_2$ ($a_1,a_2\in A$). It's obvious that the map is surjective. Then
$$\begin{array}{ccc}&&F/E \\ &\nearrow&\downarrow\\ A &\rightarrow & \Omega'_{A/R} \\ & \searrow &\downarrow \\ && F/E\end{array}$$
Thus $F/E \to \Omega'_{A/R}\to F/E$ is isomorphism. Which means $A\to \Omega'_{A/R}$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If u plug $im(d)$ in place of $M$ you will get splitting of $d$ (by universal propery of $im(d)$). More precisely $\Omega_{A/R} = Im(d)\oplus \Omega'$. Its easy to see that for nonzero $\Omega'$ this contradicts uniqness property.